# How can i remove the spaces or padding between the bars as well as the blank spaces in divs in chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, charts, chart.js

I am facing an issue in adjusting the width of each container in chartjs.
Please have a look into this and provide your input to fix this issue.
I am using a single <div> in a loop to print 3 types of data in different divs.

Here in the screenshot, first chart is proper. But in the 2nd and 3rd one there are spaces between the BARs. So please help me to remove those spaces.

Please have a look into this attached picture for better clarity.
[image]

Source code :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="barChartContainer" class="chartAreaWrapper" style="display: inline-block">
            <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CHART PROBLEM</title>
    <style>
        .chartAreaWrapper {
            height: 300px;
            margin:0!important;
            padding:0!important;
            /*     overflow-x: scroll; */
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0-rc.1/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-+UYTD5L/bU1sgAfWA0ELK5RlQ811q8wZIocqI7+K0Lhh8yVdIoAMEs96wJAIbgFvzynPm36ZCXtkydxu1cs27w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="barChartContainer" class="chartAreaWrapper" style="display: inline-block">
            <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let myChart = undefined;
    function random_rgba() {
        let r = Math.round, g = Math.random, b = 255;
        return 'rgba(' + r(g() * b) + ',' + r(g() * b) + ',' + r(g() * b) + ', 0.7)';
    }

    let jsonData = { "xAsix": ["Skipped", "Passed", "Failed"], "dataSet": [{"data": [0, 28, 12], "label": "test" }, { "data": [3, 0, 0], "label": "dit2" }, { "data": [6, 0, 0], "label": "Xerces_JavaDriversHP" }, { "data": [12, 0, 0], "label": "Sun_Xerces" }, { "data": [1, 0, 0], "label": "Sun_Dad" }, { "data": [1, 0, 0], "label": "JavaConn-LnxDIT" }, { "data": [0, 31, 1], "label": "HP_Xerces" }, { "data": [6, 0, 0], "label": "HP_JavaDrivers" }, { "data": [0, 30, 2], "label": "HP" }, { "data": [2, 0, 0], "label": "DIT-JavaConn" }, { "data": [4, 0, 0], "label": "DIT" }, { "data": [1, 0, 0], "label": "DAD_Sun" }, { "data": [0, 1, 0], "label": "DADDrivers_HP" }, { "data": [6, 0, 0], "label": "Auto" }] }

    console.log("jsonData--->", jsonData);

    const label = jsonData.xAsix;
    console.log(label);
    const dataset = jsonData.dataSet;
    console.log("dataset len::" + dataset.length);
    if (dataset.length > 0) {
        let maxEle = 0;
        dataset.forEach((e, i) => {
            let positiveValue = 0;
            e.data = e.data.map(value => {
                positiveValue += !value && 1;
                return value || undefined
            });
            maxEle = maxEle < positiveValue ? positiveValue : maxEle;
            e.skipNull = true;
            e.backgroundColor = [random_rgba(i)];
            e.borderColor = ["rgba(255,159,64,0.2)"];
            e.barPercentage = 0.9;
            //e.barThickness = 50;
            //e.barThickness = 'flex';
            e.categoryThickness = 'flex';
            e.maxBarThickness= 50;
            e.minBarLength= 30;
            e.categoryPercentage = 1;

        });
        const Containerwidth = dataset.length * dataset[0].data.length * 50 + 250;
        document.getElementById('barChartContainer').style.width = Containerwidth + 100 + 'px'
        console.log(dataset);
        if (myChart) {
            myChart.destroy();
            console.log(myChart);
        }
        var element = $('#barChart');
        document.getElementById("barChart").style.display = "block";

        myChart = new Chart(element, {

            type: 'bar',
            exportEnabled: true,
            //animationEnabled: true,
            categoryThickness: 'flex',
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            data: {
                labels: label,
                datasets: dataset,

            },
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],

            options: {
                skipNull: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function () {
                        var sourceCanvas = myChart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = myChart.scales['y'].width - 10;
                        var copyHeight = myChart.scales['y'].height + myChart.scales['y'].top + 10;
                        //var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-FuelSpend").getContext("2d");
                        //targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
                        //targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                    }
                },

                scales: {

                    x: {
                        /*ticks:{
                              autoSkip:false,
                              maxRotation: 90,
                            minRotation: 90
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                           offsetGridLines: false
                       },       
                      stacked: true,*/
                    },
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    },

                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        display: function (context) {
                            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 0;
                        },
                        color: 'black',
                        anchor: 'end',
                        align: 'top',
                        font: {
                            size: 10,
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        fontSize: '8px',
                        boxWidth: 60,
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            right: 10
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        myChart.render();

    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your container width factors in all dataset values, but the zero values aren't displayed in the bar chart.

I think if you subtract the width of the zero values when you calculate the container width, that might help.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. I will try this and let you know whether it is working or not.

Comment: @Andrew Hi Andrew, this logic is not working. When i am subtracting the no of zero values from the container width, it reducing the size for all the container.

Comment: @doub1ejack plz help